# Foreach loop average of previous rows

Tags: php, foreach

I have an foreach loop that takes some values from a MySQL database. The foreach it's very simple but with about 100 rows, like:

```
foreach($values as $value){}
```

what i'm trying to do but i don't know how it's to make inside the foreach the average of the previous 5 rows. So starting from the 5th row to do the average of the rows 1-5 then on the row 6 to do the average of rows 2-6 etc.

---

later edit, an simple example
ex:

```
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$i = 0;
foreach($values as $value){
if $i > 5{$average = (1+2+3+4+5)/5 }
// and here continue like if $i = 6 {$average = (2+3+4+5+6)/5}
// if $i = 7 {$average = (3+4+5+6+7)/5}
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more or show us an example of the expected outcome?

Comment: what do you want the result to look like.. an array with averages

Comment: i've made a simple example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($values as $i => $value) {
    $total += $value;
    if ($i >= 5) {
        $total -= $values[$i-5]; // Remove the oldest row
        $count = 5;
    } else {
        $count = $i+1;
    }
    $average = $total/$count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's getting a bit late here (Australia) but I think something along the lines of.

```
$avg = array();
$averages = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($values as $value){
    $i++;
    echo $value;
    if($i <= 5){
        $avg[] = $value;
    }else{
        $calc = 0;
        foreach($avg as $a){
             $calc = $calc + $a;
        }
        $averages = $calc / 5;
    }
}

print_r($averages);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_slice()` for slice and `array_sum()` to calculate total then average. An example here

```
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach($values as $k=>$v){
    if($k > 4){
       echo $ave = array_sum(array_slice($values, $k - 5, $k)) / 5 . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants running averages. This breaks the array up into separate groups of 5.